# Can you use Jquery to simulate the click-event on an item in a select list?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Currently I have written a jQuery statement which "highlights" a specific item in a drop down.

```
$('#mylist>option:eq(2)').prop('selected', true);
```

The above will highlight the second item and have it appear at the top of the list.

There's still a problem though, because subsequent code that I have written is behaving as though no option was chosen from the list.

Is there a way, using jQuery, to simulate the actual "clicking" on an item in a select list?

Comment: Unfortunately none of the suggestions have worked.  Any others would be appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

After the line you have above, you should try `$('#myList').trigger('click');` I don't know if that will fix your problem, but that triggers a click event on this element.

Answer (score 0):

As directly from the jQuery docs you can simulate as follows:

```
$( "#target" ).click();
```

See: http://api.jquery.com/click/